# Sending values to the server using json Array

Tags: android

i need to send some values to the server using the android volley library. But I'm unable to send the values in the JSON array format. I have tried many tutorials but i couldn't get any solution for sending JsonArray. Please give me a solution .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button button;
public String Url = "http://www.apsox.com/appdata/communication/createlocksviamobileapp";
public static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public String jsonResponse;
public static TextView txtResponse;
public String JsonString = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            makeJsonArrayRequest();
        }
    });
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}


public void makeJsonArrayRequest() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    try {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                txtResponse.setText(response.toString());
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                txtResponse.setText(error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("lock_name", "testing");
                params.put("lock_code", "2222287776554");
                params.put("details", "this is a testing lock");
                params.put("owner_userid", "1");
                params.put("master_security_phone", "Not Set");
                params.put("master_security_code", "Not Set");
                params.put("remote_lock_access_code", "1234");
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    } catch (JsonIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: if you can show your code, people can help to you. Also you can some research about Retrofit.

Comment: plz check the above code

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you 
Try to build your Json first and send it as String using StringRequest to the server 
In your Server Side parse String to Json Object to work with it